# CakePHP Expiring Headers (Plugins)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

I have developed a really easy web application based on CakePHP. I am currently running some speed test and in order to optimise the performance I used .htaccess to turn on some Apache modules such as mod_deflate. However I am struggling with the expiring headers.
I have found a couple of solutions and this is my current htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/release
   RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
   RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Using YSlow I can see that some of the assets have the right value, however some js/css files coming form plugins (/app/Plugins/X/webroot) are not changing the value.

I have also tried to add a htaccess file in the Plugin folder as well but nothing changed. I am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check [plugin assets](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-assets) seems all your plugin static files handled by dispatcher this is reason of wrong headers. So, try to lead official documentation and create symbolic link